# Parse.com: Filtrar linhas que possui um termo em uma coluna

Tags: php, libcurl, parse

Quero que a API do [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/) retorne somente as linhas que possui uma determinada palavrar, simulando uma pesquisa na tabela.

Exemplo da tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O códio que eu tentei

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={ "body": { "$in": [ "Google" ] } }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/posts
```

No exemplo, somente as linhas que possui "*Google*" na coluna **Body** seriam retornadas para o site.

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: O parse não está retornando resultados. Como se o operador $in não fosse apropriado para essa função.